# php not "echo-ing" the javascript correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to show a different iframe depending on the age of the visitor without a redirection / refresh.

However after verifying the visitors age, the javascript is not being applied correctly, or at all.

I keep ending up with a blank iframe.
Someone please take a look at my code below:

```
<html>
<head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<form method="post">
    <input type="date" name="dob"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Age" />
</form>
<?php
$minAge = 18; // You might read this from a file/database.
$minAge *= 3600*24*365.25;  // $minAge in seconds

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $birth_date = strtotime($_POST['dob']);
    $now = strtotime("now");
    $age = $now - $birth_date; // age is in seconds
    if($age > $minAge)
        echo '<script>$("#myiframe").attr("src", "http://URL1.com");</script>';
    else
        echo '<script>$("#myiframe").attr("src", "http://URL2.com");</script>';
} ?>
<iframe id="myiframe"></iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: Waiiit... if you do that with PHP, what do you need PHP for? Why not just `echo '<iframe src="http://URL1.com"></iframe>';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You js is firing before `iframe` is added to the DOM. You can move your php code (at least rendering, i.e. `echo`) under the `iframe` tag or use something like `$(document).ready(function(){<...>})`. By the way, there is a more elegant way :

```
<?php
   $minAge = 18; // You might read this from a file/database.
   $minAge *= 3600*24*365.25;  // $minAge in seconds

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $birth_date = strtotime($_POST['dob']);
      $now = strtotime("now");
      $age = $now - $birth_date; // age is in seconds
?>

    <iframe id = "myiframe"
            src = "<?php echo ($age > $minAge ? 'http://URL1.com' : 'http://URL2.com'); ?> ">
    </iframe>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I never thought of that ! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

When your script runs, the DOM does not have the iframe rendered yet. You need to move your iframe above the php code segment that renders the script tag.